# Infragistics Get Name-Property trough Cell Click c#

Tags: c#, winforms, grid, infragistics

I have created more than 5 GRID for which there are a few column that are empty/zero. These are numbered as example 1,2,3...

I have already implemented that I can select and deselect single cells for this columns.

Now my question is (and I am still very inexperienced with Infragistics)

**How do I get the `Name Property` of my grid just by clicking on it?**

Some parameters I could read out like the cells.index or the rows.index, but I want to know for another method the exact `Name Property` in which just the cell was clicked.

Via the event handler I let all my grids into the cells click method

```cs
private void GRD_LIST_Grid_ClickCell(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ClickCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cell.Column.ToString().Contains("BAHN") && e.Cell.Tag == "1") //1-5 Column have the name "BAHN", the Tag is for an flag if the cell is clicked before
    {
        e.Cell.Selected = false;
        e.Cell.Tag = null;
        SetPrio(e.Cell.Row.Index, e.Cell.Column.Index);
    }
    else if (e.Cell.Column.ToString().Contains("BAHN") && e.Cell.Tag == null)
    {
        SetPrio(e.Cell.Row.Index, e.Cell.Column.Index);
        e.Cell.Tag = "1";
    }

    //when the cell is click show the cell in green
    if (e.Cell.Tag == "1")
    {
        e.Cell.Row.Cells[e.Cell.Column.ToString()].Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
    else if (e.Cell.Tag == null)
    {
        e.Cell.Row.Cells[e.Cell.Column.ToString()].Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(234,244,243);
    }

    ClearSelectedRow(); //a Method where i set all grids in an array and clear all rows because i dont know which grid i am
}
```

Comment: When you wrote "GRID_NAME" do you meant the `Name` property of the `Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid`?

Comment: Yes exactly the name property, add it to the text. But is it possible and if so, to get the name property through the click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the [`ClickCell`](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid%7Einfragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragrid%7Eclickcell_ev) event occurs the first parameter of the event handler is sender and in this case it's the `Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid` source. Therefore, it is possible to get the grid name like in code below:

```cs
private void GRD_LIST_Grid_ClickCell(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ClickCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid ugrid)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"The ClickCell event is raised by '{ugrid.Name}'");         
    }
}
```